# Java string split into array, should I store in variable or not?

Tags: java, arrays, string, optimization, split

With our project we are going for MAXIMUM possible "speed". Would it be faster to split the string multiple times or to store it in a variable and use it?

Example

```
    String example = "1,2,3,4";
    System.out.println(example.split(",")[0]);
    System.out.println(example.split(",")[1]);
    System.out.println(example.split(",")[3]);
    System.out.println(example.split(",")[4]);
```

or

```
    String[] example = "1,2,3,4".split(",");
    System.out.println(example[0]);
    System.out.println(example[1]);
    System.out.println(example[2]);
    System.out.println(example[3]);
```

Which one would execute in less time?

Comment: `String[] example = "1,2,3,4".split(",");` if your string is long and you need to use all sub strings. then its good to store in array as `.split()` is time consuming

Comment: Besides efficiency, there's another benefit to storing the `String[]` as in your second example: if the split code changes (for instance, you want to split on `", *"` instead), you only need to make one change, not four. That means there's less of a chance that you'll miss one of the changes, which means less chance of a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting Reece's answer to the test, I used this code

```
    long startTime, endTime;

    int amountOfStrings=10000;

    System.err.println("Generating "+amountOfStrings+" String(s)");
    startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
    String example="";
    for(int i=1; i<amountOfStrings-1; i++) {
        example+=i+",";
    }
    example+=amountOfStrings;
    endTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.err.println("Done in "+(endTime-startTime)+"ms");

    System.err.println("Taking the multisplit-approach");
    startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
    for(int i=0; i<amountOfStrings-1; i++) {
        System.out.println(example.split(",")[i]);
    }
    endTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.err.println("Done in "+(endTime-startTime)+"ms");

    System.err.println("Taking the onesplit-approach");
    startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
    String[] data=example.split(",");
    for(int i=0; i<amountOfStrings-1; i++) {
        System.out.println(data[i]);
    }
    endTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.err.println("Done in "+(endTime-startTime)+"ms");
```

Executed this command:

```
$ java -jar ~/Desktop/Untitled.jar > ~/Desktop/Untitled.log
```

And got this output:

```
Generating 10000 String(s)
Done in 292ms
Taking the multisplit-approach
Done in 3906ms
Taking the onesplit-approach
Done in 275ms
```

This clearly indicates that the onesplit-approach (`String[] data=example.split(",")`) is much faster than the multisplit-approach (`example.split(",")[i]`), using 10,000 Strings.

Sidenote: Using 100 Strings is the multisplit-approach 24ms and the onesplit-approach 6ms, 10 String multisplit 1ms and onesplit 0ms. I don't expect the multisplit-approach to be faster when using more numbers.

Happy coding :) -Charlie

Answer (score 4):

In general, working with arrays is pretty fast and parsing Strings is not, so parsing the String only once and then working with the array will be significantly faster.

Anyhow, this is easily measurable, just create a for with a few thousand elements and try both options to see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Following is faster

```
String[] example = "1,2,3,4".split(",");
```

Proof:

```
Time taken to run first method 10000 times: 640 ms
Time taken to run second method 10000 times: 531 ms

Time taken to run first method 100000 times: 4144 ms
Time taken to run second method 100000 times: 3763 ms
```